# number pattern printing in python

Tags: python

I want to print following number pattern in python 3

If user input is 5

```
  1
  22
  333
  4444
```

I am doing following in python, but getting error.

```
for i in range(1,int(input())): 
   print(str(i) + " ")*i
```

It gives me following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

How to do it in python?

Comment: `print(str(i)*i)`

Comment: Yes. You are `i` should multiply string not the return value of print

Comment: What if I do not want to use `str`? can we do it without `str`

Comment: @Aran-Fey What if I do not want to use str? can we do it without str – Neil 2 mins ago

Comment: Yep. `print(f"{i}"*i)`

Comment: Why on earth would you want to avoid `str`?

Comment: Its a requirement, some coding challenge

Comment: In that case I'd recommend ignoring the challenge and spending your time on something more productive.

Comment: @Neil, check my answer, it doesn't use `str` at all.

Comment: As @Aran said, even if you avoid `str`, `print` uses str (or in deep `__str__`) to display it.

Comment: `print(i * (10 ** i - 1) // 9)` This does not use `str` anywhere. Purely arithmetic operation.

Comment: @Neil, try to mention next time that it's arithmetic task ;)

Answer (score 1):

You’re just missing a pair of brackets:

```
print((str(i) + " ")*i)
```

Comment: The space isn't correct.  Look at the expected output, then compare to yours.  Yours carries one of the originals bugs.

Comment: That’s true, but I hate being that picky here, the main question was why his code does not work. With that fix, it will run and the missing space will be an easy fix. That helps more than serving people everything on a silver platter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
    for _ in range(i):
        print(i, end="")
    print()  # new line
```

Also you can multiply value to list and unpack it into print:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
    print(*([i] * i), sep="")
```

**But** most obvious variant is to use `str`:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
    print(str(i) * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,int(input())): 
   print(str(i)*i)
```

You were multiplying the return value of print and " " is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed a pair of brackets. Also, the additional space `" "` can be removed to get your desired output.

```
for i in range(1, int(input())): 
   print(str(i)*i)
```

Comment: Yea, its not needed. I thought to remove, but my heart said "No, OP should have a reason.."